# View pager scale animation - images one after another

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, scaleanimation

I am using Viewpager to implement walkthrough, there is one unique part to it. Here is the image of it.

There are 3 images basically we wish to display 1 by 1. The unique part is that, other image are behind the image. I am not having idea how can i do this. Any idea how we can do something like this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to use coverflow widget.

Here is one reference link.[Coverflow in android](https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow)

Answer (score 1):

Its called **FancyCoverFlow**.

**FancyCoverFlow** is a *flexible Android widget providing out of the box view* transformations to give your app a unique look and feel .

Please check out Below Links

1. [ANDROID COVERFLOW WIDGET](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html)
2. [Open Source CoverFlow view](https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow)
3. [FeatureCoverFlow](https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow)